# Create Selenium report in Eclipse (Junitreport doesn't show)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, ant, eclipse-plugin

I followed the steps on creating a report in eclipse (http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/), however the junitreport does not show up Edit configurations section at the end.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Could I recommend that you use Maven instead?  Maven is arguably a better alternative to ant.  Much easier to manage. As far as your problem goes.. are you able to at least run the tests as jUnit?

Comment: No, I am new to Maven and ant could you explain how to set it up in Maven?  I need a finished report list once I run my test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Maven or Ant to be generating the report for you. Maven's Surefire and Surefire report plugins will give you what you need. Alternatively, if you followed the steps in that document as you say, you just need to configure an ant build properly.